# How to retrieve message after last retry in a JMS, ActiveMQ and SimpleMessageListenerContainer setup?

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms, message-listener

I have a Spring JMS, ActiveMQ setup where I use SimpleMessageListenerContainer which I associated with POJO message listener. I have defined a RedeliveryPolicy where if there are exceptions in POJO message listener the message is send to DLQ after 4 tries. I would like to have access the message after the retries are exhausted, is it possible to with SMLC? What about DefaultMessageListenerContainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another container listening on the DLQ.

Or you can use `JmsTemplate.receive()` on the DLQ to get them on-demand.

Comment: Is there no way to get reference to the message (Maybe just before it is sent to DLQ) without having to listen on the DLQ? The requirement is not to touch DLQ.

Comment: FYI, the idea is: Attempt to have the message sent 4 times, if it fails take the message after the last attempt and mark it as "Error" in the Database. Leave the DLQ to be monitored for exceptional cases.

Comment: [JMS 2.0 made `JMSXDeliveryCount` mandatory](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html). Some 1.1 brokers support it. So you could use the count to determine how many attempts have been made. `"JMSXDeliveryCount is not a new property; it was defined in JMS 1.1. However, in JMS 1.1, it was optional for a JMS provider to actually set it, which meant application code that used it was not portable. In JMS 2.0, it becomes mandatory for JMS providers to set this property, allowing portable applications to make use of it."`

Comment: JMSXDeliveryCount helped in creating a solution without listening on DLQ.